# PHP how to remove key from multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to remove key 1 from PHP array. I know how to achieve this by using foreach loop but i want `array_filter` solution. Anyone know How can I achieve this by using array filter method?

PHP Array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5000
            [1] => 25
            [2] => 44
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5000
            [1] => 25
            [2] => 48
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5000
            [1] => 26
            [2] => 44
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5000
            [1] => 26
            [2] => 48
        )

)
```

Expected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5000
            [1] => 44
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5000
            [1] => 48
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5000
            [1] => 44
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5000
            [1] => 48
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `array_filter()` for this purpose. Use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) instead

```
$newArr = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item){
    $carry[] = [$item[0], $item[2]];
    return $carry;
});
```

Check result in [demo](https://ideone.com/0XRWgR)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `array_filter` for this. `array_filter` processes the values, but you want to remove a specific key.

Use `array_splice()` to remove an index and have all following increments adjust.

```
foreach ($array as &$element) {
    array_splice($element, 1, 1);
}
```

The `&` makes this a reference variable, so modifying the variable affects the elements in the array.

Comment: To be clear, `array_filter()` can be set to assess keys (though not the default behavior).  Regardless, `array_splice()` is a better choice to reindex the subarrays.

Comment: It can access keys, but since it preserves them in the result, it won't renumber the remaining elements. You would have to use `$element = array_values($element);` afterward to fix the indexes.

Answer (score -1):

If processing an array of indexed arrays, @Barmar's iterated `array_splice()` calls are ideal because they re-index the subarrays after the targeted key is removed.  Here is a functional and dynamic variation on his answer.

([Both Demos](https://3v4l.org/jIWET))

```
$array = [
    [5000, 25, 44],
    [5000, 25, 48],
    [5000, 26, 44],
    [5000, 26, 48],
];

$omitKey = 1;

var_export(
    array_map(
        function($row) use($omitKey) {
            array_splice($row, $omitKey, 1);
            return $row;
        },
        $array
    )
);
```

If you have an array of associative arrays (not indexed), then `array_splice()` is not the correct tool because it relies on positions, not keys.  Use `unset()` instead.

```
$array = [
    ['a' => 5000, 'b' => 25, 'c' => 44],
    ['a' => 5000, 'b' => 25, 'c' => 48],
    ['a' => 5000, 'b' => 26, 'c' => 44],
    ['a' => 5000, 'b' => 26, 'c' => 48],
];

$omitKey = 'b';

var_export(
    array_map(
        function($row) use($omitKey) {
            unset($row[$omitKey]);
            return $row;
        },
        $array
    )
);
```